# Regular Expressions parenthesis inside parenthesis

Tags: java, regex, string, windows, vbscript

I have this logic programming software that can output results in a text file in the following form:

```
[-a(b), +i(c), +i(d)] 
[-a(f(g(a))), -a(f(a,b)), -a(f(c)), -a(f(d)), -a(b)]
...
```

Which can extend to hundreds or thousands of lines.

I just want to be able to narrow this number by removing lines that contains parenthesis inside parenthesis (in other terms, functions inside predicates) like `-a(f(g(a)))` and `-a(f(c))`... And keep all the other lines.

Can anybody guide me and perhaps provide me a simple example on how to achieve this in the simplest manner, nothing fancy at all, maybe in a VBScript or a Batch (Yes I am on windows), that reads the content of the text file and removes the unappropriated lines.

**Edit: vbs working sample**

```
Dim re, targetString
Set re = New RegExp
With re
  .Pattern = "\([^()]*\("
  .Global = False
  .IgnoreCase = False
End With

targetString = "[-a(f(g(a))), -a(f(a,b)), -a(f(c)), -a(f(d)), -a(b)]"

if re.Test(targetString) <> True Then
    MsgBox "valid",0,"test"
else
    MsgBox "invalid",0,"test"
end if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching nested parentheses is always a tricky business for regexes since recursive structures are not regular. But in your examples, you could simply look for lines where two opening parentheses follow each other without an intervening closing parenthesis:

```
if (/\([^()]*\(/.test(line)) {
    // discard line
} else {
    // keep line
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
\(     # Match (
[^()]* # Match any number of characters except parentheses 
\(     # Match another (
```

Comment: @Cicada if you are not guaranteed there are no intervening characters, then no.

Comment: @Cicada: You mean a literal search for `))`? It would work in the provided examples, yes. Not sure whether this would work generally (think of function calls like `a(f(b), c)` etc.)

Comment: @Cicada - it might not be quicker, though - need to iterate more chars.

Comment: I've just tested this regex in a small vbs but it seems to always return valid for both examples that do and do not contain nested parenthesis. It might be me, I know that I suck at vbs. Ill post the code in the question

Answer (score 2):

Use grep

```
grep -v '([^()]*(' file.txt
```

Comment: Let's hope he has Cygwin installed, then :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker - **Grep for Windows**  http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete Perl solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open IN, 'in.txt' or die "can't open input file";
open OUT, '>out.txt' or die "can't open output file";

while (<IN>)
{
   unless (/([\(]\w*){2}/)
   {
       print OUT $_;
   }
}
```

In my opinion, it is much faster to [install Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) and use it to solve your problem than to try to do this in VBScript.  (Yes, I am biased, but Perl is a far superior tool).